# Magnolia CMS to Active Directory Connection via LDAP

Tags: ldap, magnolia

I am able to Authenticate user using LDAP server but I am unable to get Group details present for the user in LDAP, and hence I am unable to LOGIN to Magnolia Admin Central.

Can anyone please guide me for the same

### Here are the config files which I have used:

```
JASS.CONFIG
magnolia {
 info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule optional;
 info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.LDAPAuthenticationModule requisite
 skip_on_previous_success=true;
 info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthorizationModule required;
 };
```

---

```
LDAP.Properties:
#Initial factory class
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory

# LDAP url
java.naming.provider.url=ldap://localhost:1389/

java.naming.security.principal=uid=admin,ou=system
java.naming.security.credentials=xxxxxx

java.naming.security.authentication=simple

initialSearchAttributes=dc=xyz,dc=co,dc=uk
Organization=o
OrganizationUnit=ou
CommonName=cn
Surname=sn
GivenName=givenname
uid=uid
dn=dn
mail=mail
Password=userPassword
Language=language

roleResolverClass=info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.resolver.MagnoliaRoleResolver

groupResolverClass=info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.resolver.OpenLDAPGroupResolver
groupSearchContext=ou=groups,o=xyz,dc=xyz,dc=co,dc=uk
groupSearchFilter=(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=member))
groupMembershipAttributeValue=dn
GroupId=cn
```

---

I have added configured ldap.properties inside magnolia.properties and created 
one user manager "External" as defined in the documentation in magnolia, apart from this I have not done any changes in Magnolia admin central.

While using LDAP-Tester jar provided in the documentation, I am able to connect to LDAP but no groups are returned.

---

DEBUG LOG OF MAGNOLIA

```
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.FormLogin 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- handle login for pagrawa
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- initializing user pagrawa
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- getting user manager for realm all
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- creating jcr session users by thread http-bio-8080-exec-3
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.core.MagnoliaAccessProvider 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- getEditor(session-admin-452)
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.core.MagnoliaAccessProvider 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- compile permissions for admin[info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.MagnoliaJRAdminPrincipal] at users
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/system'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 1ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/system' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/admin'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 1ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/admin' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/public'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 2ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/public' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.LDAPUtils 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- JNDI config file [WEB-INF/config/ldap.properties] defined under key [jndi.ldap.config.ldap] will be used.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.ConnectionFactory 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Trying to log in as uid=admin,ou=system with a password.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.ConnectionFactory 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Successful initialization dirContext.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.resolver.OpenLDAPGroupResolver 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Searching groups for pagrawa with: (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=member))
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/admin'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 1ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/admin' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.resolver.MagnoliaRoleResolver 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- LDAP User pagrawa doesn't exist in magnolia repository. Create this user in admin realm and attach to him appropriate groups/roles. If you want get groups/roles attached to this user directly from ldap/ad use OpenLDAPGroupResolver/ADGroupResolver.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- initialized user pagrawa in 85ms
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- initializing user pagrawa
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- getting user manager for realm all
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/system'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 1ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/system' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/admin'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 0ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/admin' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/public'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 2ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/public' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.LDAPUtils 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- JNDI config file [WEB-INF/config/ldap.properties] defined under key [jndi.ldap.config.ldap] will be used.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.ConnectionFactory 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Trying to log in as uid=admin,ou=system with a password.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.ConnectionFactory 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Successful initialization dirContext.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.resolver.OpenLDAPGroupResolver 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Searching groups for pagrawa with: (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=member))
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Executing query "select * from [mgnl:user] where name() = 'pagrawa' and isdescendantnode(['/admin'])".
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Retrieving node took 2ms (isInstallationPhase: false): path = <null>
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.RepositoryBackedSecurityManager 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Could not find principal node 'pagrawa' of primary type 'mgnl:user' under startnode '/admin' in workspace 'users'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.resolver.MagnoliaRoleResolver 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- LDAP User pagrawa doesn't exist in magnolia repository. Create this user in admin realm and attach to him appropriate groups/roles. If you want get groups/roles attached to this user directly from ldap/ad use OpenLDAPGroupResolver/ADGroupResolver.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthenticationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- initialized user pagrawa in 21ms
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.LDAPUtils 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- JNDI config file [WEB-INF/config/ldap.properties] defined under key [jndi.ldap.config.ldap] will be used.
INFO   info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.ConnectionFactory 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Trying to log in as cn=prateek,ou=users,o=diligenta,dc=diligenta,dc=co,dc=uk with a password.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.ldap.ConnectionFactory 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Login succeeded.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthorizationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Roles: {}
DEBUG  info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JCRAuthorizationModule 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Groups: {}
DEBUG  info.magnolia.monitoring.SystemMonitor 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Memory values: max = 475mb, total = 475mb, free = 48mb -> remaining = 48mb / thresholds = 50mb or 10%
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.RequestAttributeStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Session initialized in order to set attribute 'javax.security.auth.Subject' to 'Subject:
    Principal: info.magnolia.cms.security.ExternalUser@3c82d1f9
    Principal: info.magnolia.cms.security.Realm$RealmImpl@179a1
    Principal: RoleListImpl[name=roles,list=[]]
    Principal: GroupListImpl[name=groups,list=[]]
    Principal: PrincipalCollectionImpl[name=PrincipalCollection]
'. You should avoid using session when possible!
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Content type for http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/ is not set, status code of response is 302.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- releasing jcr sessions
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- releasing jcr sessions
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- logged out jcr session: session-admin-452 by thread http-bio-8080-exec-3
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Handling URI: /magnoliaAuthor/ - Path info: null
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.WebContextImpl 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- new WebContextImpl() info.magnolia.context.WebContextFactoryImpl$1@1667e673
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [: not] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [:  pattern: /.magnolia] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [: not] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [:  pattern: /.magnolia] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [: not] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [:  pattern: /.magnolia] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [: not] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [:  pattern: /.magnolia] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [admincentralFileUpload:  pattern: /.magnolia/admincentral] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [registrationCss:  pattern: /.resources/enterprise/css/registration.css] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [registrationImages:  pattern: /.resources/enterprise/images/registration/*.gif] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.FormLogin 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- handle login for null
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [allButActivationHandler: not pattern: /.magnolia/activation] fired 21
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 21
DEBUG  info.magnolia.multisite.filters.MultiSiteFilter 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Determined domain as localhost on address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1. The assigned site is fallback.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- There's no variation named 'all'. Serving site 'fallback'.
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [BypassWhenNotInAdminCentral: not pattern: /.magnolia] fired 10
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 10
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [BypassWhenNotAuthenticated: not] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [BypassWhenNoQueryParameters: not] fired 1
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [BypassWhenVaadinRequest:  pattern: /.magnolia/admincentral] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [dotMagnolia:  pattern: /.magnolia] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [resources:  pattern: /.resources] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [login:  pattern: /.resources/defaultMagnoliaLoginForm] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [logout:  pattern: /.magnolia/pages/logout.html] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [adminJavascript:  pattern: /.magnolia/pages/javascript.js] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [registrationCss:  pattern: /.resources/enterprise/css/registration.css] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- voter [registrationImages:  pattern: /.resources/enterprise/images/registration/*.gif] fired 0
DEBUG  info.magnolia.voting.DefaultVoting 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- highest vote is now 0
WARN   info.magnolia.cms.security.PermissionUtil 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- no permissions found for [info.magnolia.cms.security.ExternalUser@3c82d1f9]
DEBUG  info.magnolia.multisite.filters.SiteUriSecurityFilter 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- Skipping site permission check for user pagrawa, permission read to access uri / on site fallback
DEBUG  info.magnolia.multisite.filters.SiteUriSecurityFilter 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- User pagrawa has NOT been granted permission read to access uri /
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- releasing jcr sessions
DEBUG  info.magnolia.context.AbstractRepositoryStrategy 16.11.2016 13:57:26 -- releasing jcr sessions
```

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is that UserManager can't be located. Which would point to error in your configuration.

My guess is that realm name is not matching in your config file and in magnolia configuration. Check out documentation for more details https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/LDAP+Connector+module

Once confirmed that all is set correctly, if the groups are not returned, check first if group membership is really found by DNs you configured or whether UIDs are denoting membership.

If that is not the issue, check if your `groupSearchFilter` and/or `groupSearchContext` are configured correctly.

You can also try to get any tool that can query LDAP and run those queries by yourself to see that it locates groups you want and members are in them.

Comment: Hi Jan,

Thanks a lot for your response, since I am unable to add my full query here in the comment, hence I have modified the question with my new error log could you please guide me for the same.

Comment: Uh, it really depends on your configuration a lot at this point. If the groups are not returned, I'd first check if group membership is really found by DN s you configured or whether UIDs are denoting membership. If that is not the issue, check if your groupSearchFilter and/or groupSearchContext are configured correctly. You can also try to get any tool that can query LDAP and run those queries by yourself to see that it locates groups you want and members are in them.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the value in my groupSearchFilter and it worked...Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi Vivek-0103, I've updated the answer to contain the explanation from the comment that helped you to resolve your issue. It would be nice for other people with similar problem in the future, if you could mark the answer as correct now.